# How does one debug the KVM subsystem?

Tags: linux, debugging, kernel, qemu

I was recently debugging the QEMU source code and there are endpoints like kvm_ioctl, kvm_vm_ioctl, kvm_vcpu_ioctl, kvm_device_ioctl which interact with the /dev/kvm and VM and VCPU file descriptors to make everything happen.

But when the code calls kvm_vm_ioctl(KVM_CREATE_VM) for example, an ioctl@plt is called and the context switches to the kernel.

**How do I debug from here on?**

Some people have told to modify and insmod kvm.ko with printk(), but I cannot find kvm.ko anywhere, not even in lsmod.

Platform: Raspberry Pi 4 (Raspbian Lite 64-bit)

Note: /dev/kvm is present but lsmod doesn't show kvm module.

Comment: What is CONFIG_KVM set to?

Comment: CONFIG_KVM=y in /boot/config-$(uname -r)

Comment: That means it's built in.  There is no module.

Comment: Do you really need to debug KVM in the kernel, though? Like any other syscall, if it's behaving correctly you can restrict yourself to only debugging the userspace program that uses it.

Comment: @PeterMaydell correct, I am debugging QEMU. But I want to see the inner workings of KVM when QEMU calls ioctl(/dev/kvm)

Comment: Then you would need to debug the kernel, which (a) is not trivial and (b) requires you to understand a different and equally complicated piece of software. A "divide and conquer" approach to solving your problem would suggest that you treat the kernel as a black box until and unless you're confident that the issue is in the kernel, not in QEMU.